# Git: Working on master instead of own repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

First off, I have a very simple understanding of git. Here's my workflow...

1. I git cloned a repo

   git clone 'url to remote repo'
2. I then created a branch

   git branch my-feature
3. I checkout to this branch

   git checkout my-feature
4. I do some work
5. I add my changes

   git add .
6. I commit

   git commit -m 'some changes'

Now this is where I'm getting confused. After my commit I see my commit with message in the remote repo, BitBucket. But I've not done a push yet.

7. I type

   git push
8. I get a message saying: git push --set-upstream origin new-feature ,
   so I do that
9. But it appears that my commit at step 6, is pushing into master.

So going back to step 1 should I have git forked before the git clone ?

What I thinking is: I should be on my own remote repo ?, then I could issue a pull request from my remote repo into the remote master repo that another developer could review ?

Is this correct ?
But I keep pushing into master, in other words I seem to be on master

Answer (score 2):

> After my commit I see my commit with message in the remote repo, BitBucket. But I've not done a push yet.

As far as I know, if you did not push your commit, then there is no way that commit could be showing up in Bitbucket.  This means that the commit you are seeing is some other commit, possibly an artifact from when you created the repo initially.

After you branched off master, did some work, and pushed, the branch should seemlessly go to Bitbucket and appear as a new feature branch.  To correct the upstream error, you can try pushing via the following:

```
git push -u origin my-feature
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it may well be 'artefacts' lingering. Would you recommend that I should create another folder the git fork the git clone into this so as to get off master ? in BitBucket, I want to see a lane that is master, then my branch lanes to the right. Only merged into master when I actually merge

Comment: If you branched your feature branch off master, you should already be seeing this branch diagram.

Comment: I just see the one branch, master. I can't seem to get off it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I get a list of branches.   remotes/origin/CaseToolBarList
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/Jira#168-AssignCaseOfficers
  remotes/origin/Jira#244-PriorityLevel
  remotes/origin/Jira#25-CaseDetail-UI    and finally   remotes/origin/master

Comment: According to this, the only local branch is master.